# A way of examining the order of execution of single line expression in C++ by debugging

Tags: c++

Is there a way to examine the order of execution of a single line expression which contains a few small sub expressions in C++ by the help of the debugger?

For example:
`if( a!= 6 || b!= 5)`

Can I found out what is executed first `a!=6` or `b!=5` by watching the debugger operation , how can I do that if all sub expressions are all in one line of code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `=!`? I think you mean `!=`.

Comment: 1) You mean `!=` not `=!` 2) `a != 6` goes first and `b != 5` goes second on execution.

Comment: There is no `6 || b` expression here

Comment: Order of execution of a non-optimised build is well defined but can change drastically when optimised.  Trying to debug an optimised build can be frustrating.   I suggest you inspect the generated assembler of the optimised build, either in your IDE or using one of the online compiler explorers.  Note that what you think of a variables (and even whole expressions) may have been completely optimised away by the compiler.

Comment: In this case - check the operator precedence rules. They are pretty unambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Richard Critten mentioned, you can use online compiler explorers. For example, Godbolt can give you following:

https://godbolt.org/g/Z4PrXD

So you can see that `a != 6` is checked first, and `b != 5` is checked only if the first condition fails.

Comment: Add `-O2` and check the generated code.  It's a whole new world.

Comment: @RichardCritten [this](https://godbolt.org/g/chcdwd) is probably a better example, even at higher `-O`